# Kubernetes: How I can redirect a Service to Pod's in a specific Node

Tags: kubernetes, service, nodes

Here is situation:
Lets say I have a Kubernetes setup.
I have a service and an app in Pods in multiple Nodes.
I want to configure the Service, so that it redirects(connects) incoming connections to only a Pod in a specific Node (let's say, Node1), not others.

For example, Pod's have NodeSelector features, but this is another need.

What I want/need is a little bit against the philosophy of Kubernetes (Pod failover etc), but is needed for some purpose.

Illustration:

incoming connection -> Service -> Only Pods in Node1, not others.

Thanks